# WPF DataGrid slow when filtering collectionview

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, datagrid

We are in a phase to convert our Silverlight application to WPF. Unfortunately we have found that *filtering the DataGrid in WPF is extremely slow*.

We have created two test applications to compare and profile Silverlight and WPF on the native controls. The applications load the same set of data:

- 1000 rows of mixed data - text, bool, int and enum
- 25 columns bound to the data (5 identical columns duplicated 5 times)

The DataGrid is completely virtualized, and we are binding to an ICollectionView, using a predicate to filter. The DataGrid is all virtualized:

### Data source

```
public class Data
{
   private CollectionViewSource viewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

   public Data()
   {
      var items = new List<Item>();
      // Creating 1000 Item here...
      var source = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Items };
      View = source.View;
      View.Filter = i => IsMatch(i as Item);
   }

   public ICollectionView View => viewSource.View;
}

public class Item
{
   public string Description { get; set; } = "Text here"; 
   public bool Bool { get; set; } 
   public int Value { get; set; } 
   public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } 
   public Test EnumValue { get; set; } 
   public static IEnumerable AvailableEnumValues => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test));
}
```

### XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding View}"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
          VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="False" 
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.CacheLength="2,3"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Page"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Item">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Bool}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EnumValue}" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Item.AvailableEnumValues}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TimeStamp}" Width="100"/> 
     <!-- Repeat 5 columns above 5 times -->
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Using the stopwatch on the phone we get the following results
The results are following:

- Silverlight: ~50ms
- WPF: ~1500ms

***Has anyone faced the same problem, and found a way to speed up filtering?***

From profiling we have discovered that the Silverlight datagrid seems to have specific logic handling NotifyCollectionChanged.Reset event from the collection view. A "DataGridConnection" intercepts the event and calls RefreshRows on the DataGrid. In contrast, the WPF datagrid does not have this logic, and so the NotifyCollectionChanged.Reset is intercepted by the ItemContainerGenerator, which raises an ItemsChanged event. This is handled by a Panel which clears all children leading to a very deeply nested call tree with a lot of recursive calls through a class called DescendantsWalker. This is followed by a full UpdateLayout cycle (measure and arrange), presumably through all rows and cells.

We have compared against several other DataGrid providers, and some of them do perform **MUCH** better than WPF, so it is definitely possible.

### Profiler snapshots

Below is snapshots from the the profiler sessions for SL and WPF, and an excerpt of the source code used.

**SL DataGridConnection**
[image: SL DataGridConnection]

**WPF call tree**
[image: WPF call tree]

**WPF UpdateLayout Cycle**
[image: WPF update layout cycle]